# Django Rest Framework URL Mapping for multiple apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django-rest project called `main` and under it I have created an app called `users`. So, my project has the files :-

> main/main/urls.py

and

> main/users/urls.py

In users/urls.py I have

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from users import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
```

and in the main/main/urls.py I have

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from users import urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^users/', users.urls),
]
```

However, I keep getting the error `NameError: name 'users' is not defined`. What is the correct way to set up urls when I have multiple apps? I would like to have a urls.py file for each app that is independent of the project. And in the root urls.py would include routing to different apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You import url not user, can try it

```
from users import urls as users_url
#                        ^^^^^^^^

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^users/', users_url),
    #               ^^^^^^^
]
```

but better:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.url')),
    #               ^^^^^^^
]
```

more details [including-other-urlconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Comment: Or, alternatively, `import users` and `url(r'^users/', users.urls)`